# Getting undefined error when I select a React-Complex-Tree item

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a catalogue with React-Complex-Tree but I keep getting undfined when I select an item.

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-complex-tree-catalogue-r8csf5?file=/src/Menu.jsx+

According to the [React-Complex-Tree Docs](https://rct.lukasbach.com/docs/getstarted), this is how to do it but it doesn't seem like the DataProvider is passing a value.

There's a console log to check the value.

```
import {
  UncontrolledTreeEnvironment,
  Tree,
  StaticTreeDataProvider
} from "react-complex-tree";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "react-complex-tree/lib/style-modern.css";


import { items } from "./MenuData";

// function Component({ item }) {
//     return <div className='text-4xl'>You clicked on {item.data}</div>;
// }

export default function Products() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>
          
         <UncontrolledTreeEnvironment
            dataProvider={
              new StaticTreeDataProvider(items, (item, data) => ({
                ...item,
                data
              }))
            }
            getItemTitle={(item) => item.data}
            viewState={{}}
            onPrimaryAction={(items) => {
              console.log("Setting selected item:", items[0]);
              setSelectedItem(items[0]);
            }}
          >
            <Tree treeId="tree-1" rootItem="root" treeLabel="Tree Example" />
        </UncontrolledTreeEnvironment>
        
</div>
        <div className="tabs-container h-auto mx-auto font-bold">
          Table will render here

          {/* <Component item={selectedItem} /> */}

        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```